# Select everything after a certain row in ordered SQL Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have a query that selects a bunch of rows from various tables and orders them alphabetically based on a single field (Fruit), but I want to only start selecting after a certain value is reached. Is there anyway of doing this in MS Access SQL?

Eg:

If the value is Cherry and the table, ordered alphabetically, looks like:

```
**Fruit:**

Apple

Banana

Cherry

Damson

Orange

--
```

Then I just want to select Cherry, Damson and Orange. (Sorry I couldn't think of a fruit beginning with E)

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: For future reference - Elderberry!

Comment: Sadly, no x : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_culinary_fruits

Comment: @Remou I'm confused - Elderberry is on that list, along with Lemons, Pineapple, Coconut etc.!

Comment: @Bridge Poor communication skills on my part. I voted up your comment and then it occurred to me, why stop at e? There must be a whole alphabet out there, but there is not. There is no x.

Comment: @Remou Depends how hard you look - http://www.kidsandfruit.org.au/cms/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=18&Itemid=42

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most operators can also be applied to text fields, so in your example you could use:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Fruit
WHERE   FruitName >= 'Cherry'
```

Comment: it`s not a good Solution ,
in this case operators relies on alphabets , for example if you change Damson`s place with Banana , result is same as before !

Answer (score 2):

If you create an `id` column in your `fruit table` then it would be easy to get the list of rows after a certain row.

you table will look like.

```
id          fruitname
----------- --------------------
1           Apple
2           Banana
3           Cherry
4           Damson
5           Orange
```

And query will look like.

```
SELECT * FROM fruit f 
WHERE id>=(SELECT id FROM fruit WHERE fruitname='Cherry');
```

this will result in

```
id          fruitname
----------- --------------------
3           Cherry
4           Damson
5           Orange
```

Comment: Why would you force someone to enter their fruit in alphabetical order?

Comment: What if `id` is not ordered?